# What are the differences between the characters?

Tags: dustforce

When you begin a level, you have the option to select one of four characters. What are the differences between these four characters? They don't appear to be purely cosmetic, as the third one (short girl with dusters) has a triple jump, which none of the others have.

[image: Four Janitors]

Comment: Their names are Dustman, Dustgirl, Dustkid, and Dustworth, respectively.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Gamespot's Forums](http://www.gamespot.com/dustforce/forum/differences-in-the-characters-61707099/):

> **Light Attack**
>
> - Blue: Standard length and width (height).
> - Red: About the same length, but not quite as wide as Blue's. Appears to be closer to the ground. Attack speed is either slightly slower or the same. Hard to tell.
> - Purple: Much shorter in both width and length. If you measure the length in the width of the character sprites, it is about one sprite shorter than Blue's. Attack speed is much quicker.
> - Green: Longer, with equal width. Again, measuring in sprites, the length is about one sprite longer than Blue's. Attack speed noticeably slower.
>
> **Heavy Attack**
>
> - Blue: Standard length and width (height).
> - Red: Equal length but
>     slightly wider. Possible that it is also slightly quicker. Again, hard
>     to tell.
> - Purple: Again, much shorter in length, only about half or three-fifths as long, but equally as wide. Noticeably quicker attack speed.
> - Green: Equal length but slightly wider. Equal attack speed.
>
> **Dash**
>
> - Blue: Standard.
> - Red: Slightly shorter distance covered. After five consecutive dashes, Red would be standing directly behind Blue.
> - Purple: Noticeably shorter than Blue. After Purple made five dashes, it would require an entire sixth dash to end up in the same
>     spot as Blue, so if my math is right, one dash is about one-fifth shorter than Blue's.
> - Green: Same as Red.
>
> **Jumping**
>
> - Blue: Standard
> - Red: Equal height as Blue
> - Purple: Much shorter, but has a triple jump instead of double, which equals the height of Blue.
> - Green: Higher the Blue. A double jump puts him at about one sprite-height higher than Blue's max height.
>
> *As far as I could tell, all of their wall climbing abilities are equal. There are also other things that I still need to test, like
>   acceleration and momentum, that appear to differ from one another. If
>   I have the time, I might post a video of all the comparisons.*

This is all information that I have tested, and agree with.

Edit: It's worth noting that the purple character is capable of wall-climbing a single wall higher than the other characters, because she can jump out from the wall and back onto it more times with her three jumps.

Comment: I have heard that Dustgirl (red) accelerates to max fall speed slightly faster than Dustman (blue), which has an important effect on jump heights and timings in certain situations, although the max speed is the same for both characters.

Answer (score 4):

Green with a vacuum has very high jumps, the purple girl with dusters seems to have faster attacks and very short jumps, but she has a triple jump to make up for it. I'm not sure if there are significant differences between blue and red, they might be a sort of ryu/ken deal with minor (if any) differences.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion after a few days of playing is this:

- Blue — allrounder and fast sprinter
- Red — high dash boosts, slightly higher and farther jumps because of the dash boost
- Purple — very mobile with triplejump/dash, but less height on jumps
- Green — slower sprint and dash, highest jump

Answer (score 0):

From [Gamespot Review](http://www.gamespot.com/dustforce/reviews/dustforce-review-6348739/):

> Of the four playable characters, the blue character with the broom
>   appears to be the most well-rounded one, while the purple character
>   with the feather dusters is quicker but can't jump as high. This lack
>   of information only serves as a detriment to the game and adds
>   unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Well, that's not really an answer - after all, it's really just saying that the question exists :)

Comment: Blue is balanced;Purple is faster and can't jump as high...is certainly an answer. Just not a complete answer. :P

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, the purple girl can triple jump and the green guy can blow back the spiky projectiles from the porcupine enemies, and when blowing them back they can kill another enemy. I don't know if red has anything special, and blue just seems to be special in that he is well rounded.