# Are there some levels that can't be finished with certain characters?

Tags: dustforce

I've been playing Dustforce, and just yesterday learned that [the different characters are not there simply for aesthetics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47648/what-are-the-differences-between-the-characters).

It makes perfect sense as a game-design decision that, in the overworld/hub area/level select places, you have to use different characters to access some new levels.

The other night I encountered this:

[image: One level of Dustforce has this gigantic pit to cross, with only one enemy to kill, three quarters of the way across it.]

I assumed at first that this obstacle was not conquerable with the blue character, but I discovered that dash-jumping makes it possible.

So this is strong evidence, but my ultimate question has not yet been definitively answered: Are there levels that only certain characters can finish, and if so, must you rely on trial and error or overworld suggestions to figure it out?

Comment: Haven't heard of any levels that can't be completed by every character, but reaching the door to *Wild Den* (a gold level in Forest) is much harder with Dustman / Dustgirl than with the other 2 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Dash before you jump (like in Megaman X) then double jump, you should be able to hit it with a heavy attack and possibly even a light attack, after hitting the enemy you are able to do an extra jump and wall run the ceiling to the other side of the screen.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yep, I figured this out and just hadn't gotten back here to update my post yet. I am going to leave this question open, though, for a definitive answer as to whether there are *any* levels that certain characters cannot complete.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, any level can be completed with any character.

If you're *really* unsure about a particular stage, I'd suggest you check the leaderboards, to see if there are results for all four characters, but I suspect you'll find that there are on every stage. (I don't have time to do this right now for every level or I'd check).